# Drupal like jquery popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drupal

I am making a CMS for public use and looking forward to know how the jQuery popup is setup in Drupal 7. I have searched in Google and found many jQuery popup plugins, but the problem is that Drupal has setup the popup in such a way that you can easily scroll through it.
I want to know how to make something similar to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how drupal do it but have you tried [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)? The [Dialog Element](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) is a really good "Popup"/ Overlay provider.